# Find this $a,b,c$ such that $\sqrt{9-8\sin 50^{\circ}}=a+b\sin c^{\circ}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

It is known that$$\sqrt{9-8\sin 50^{\circ}}=a+b\sin c^{\circ}$$
for exactly one set of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ where $0<c<90$

find the value 
$$\dfrac{b+c}{a}$$

my idea,$ \sin 50^\circ >\sin 45^\circ >\frac{_5}{^8} $

so$\sqrt{9-8\sin 50^{\circ}}<2$,then $a=1$

then $$\dfrac{b^2}{16}(1-\cos{(2c)})+\dfrac{b}{4}\sin{c}=1-\sin{50^{0}}$$

so $b=4$

then we have $\sin{c}-\cos{(2c)}=-\sin{50^{0}}$

then my question: How can prove this $c$ must equality 10?

Thank you everyone: yesterday,when I go to bed, I have consider this:let $f(c)=\sin{c}-\cos{(2c)}$.then we have $f(10)=\sin{10}-\cos{20}=\cos{80}-\cos{20}=2\sin{\dfrac{80-20}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{80+20}{2}}=\sin{50}$, by other hand, we have $f'(c)=\cos{c}+2\sin{2c}>0,0<c<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,so if we $f(c)=f(10)$,we must $c=10$

Comment: Why is $b=4$? What can't it be $8$ or $32$ or ...

Comment: @Aryabhata For that the LHS will for sure be $>$ RHS

Comment: @exploringnet: It may be true, but I don't see it without more work. The way it was stated was as if it is very obvious. For instance, as $c \to 0$, we have that LHS $\to 0$ for any $b$ (even large ones), so why can't $c=1$ and $b$ be larger than $4$? (And I don't see why it has to be a multiple of $4$ too, which I presume was part of the reason $4$ was chosen...).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have the following (working in degrees):

$$\cos 20 - \cos 80 = \cos(50-30) - \cos(50+30) = 2 \sin 50 \sin 30 = \sin 50$$

Thus we have that

$$1 - 2\sin^2 10 - \sin 10 = \sin 50$$

(using $\cos 20 = 1 - 2 \sin^2 10$ and $\cos 80 = \sin (90 - 80) = \sin 10$)

And so

$$9 - 8 \sin 50 = 9 - 8(1 - 2\sin^2 10 - \sin 10) = 1 + 8\sin 10 + 16\sin^2 10 = (1 + 4 \sin 10)^2$$

Thus $a=1, b=4, c=10$.

Comment: +1, Very nice. You have proved that there is one set of solutions. How does one show that  this set is unique?

Comment: @AméricoTavares: It is given that it is unique, as part of the problem statement. One just needs to find them. I agree, the question how that was determined is probably more interesting.

Comment: You are right. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: very nice , yesterday,when I go to bed, I have consider this:let $f(c)=\sin{c}-\cos{(2c)}$.then we have $f(10)=\sin{10}-\cos{20}=\cos{80}-\cos{20}=2\sin{\dfrac{80-20}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{80+20}{2}}=\sin{50}$, by other hand, we have $f'(c)=\cos{c}+2\sin{2c}>0,0<c<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,so if we $f(c)=f(10)$,we must $c=10$

Comment: @math110: Your argument that $b=4$ is not convincing though...

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin c-\cos(2c)$$
$$\implies \cos(90-c)-\cos(2c)$$
$$\implies -2\sin\Bigg(\dfrac{90+c}2\Bigg) \sin \Bigg(\dfrac{90-3c}2\Bigg)=-\sin(50^{\circ})$$
$$2\sin\theta \sin\phi=\sin 50^{\circ}$$

So, one of the solution comes when one of $\sin \theta^{\circ}$ or $\sin\phi$
is equal to $1/2$ and other is $\sin 50^{\circ}$

So, $$1)\dfrac{90+c}2=50 ;\sin\Bigg(\dfrac{90-3c}2\Bigg)=1/2$$

Or $$2)\dfrac{90-3c}2=50 ; \sin\Bigg(\dfrac{90+c}2\Bigg)=1/2$$

Case $2$ does not hold true , So, from $1$st case $c=10^{\circ}$

And as the solution is unique, it's the one we need.

Comment: Thank you exploringnet,But I think you methods don't strict,Because why $\dfrac{90+c}{2}=50$,and$ \sin{\dfrac{90-3c}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{2}$,you mean if $ab=cd$,then $a=c,b=d$,That's some mistake.

Comment: @math110 Then try quadratic solving.

Comment: @math110 Now I see after the other answer that the solution set is unique and thus if we find even one , then it's more than enough.

Answer (score -1):

Well the most forward way I think of is using the fact that $cos(2c)=1-2sin^2(c)$. This gives you some equation like:

$2X^2+X-(1+sin(50°))=0$ where $X=sin(c)$

Once you have $sin(c)$ you can get $c$ quite easily given your condition over $c$.

Comment: Thank you ,But I think this methods can't solve my question,because $X=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{9-8\sin{50^{0}}}}{4}$, So this return it.