# If such $1+4\sin{10^\circ}=a+b\sin{c^\circ}$ How find this integer $a,b$

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

**Interesting problem:**

> Assmue that：
>   $$1+4\sin{10^\circ}=a+b\sin{c^\circ}$$
>   where $a>0$,and $a,b,c$ are integers and $0<c<90^\circ$,
>
> show that $$a=1,b= 4,c=10$$ is unique solution

**Different Old Question:** see [Find this $a,b,c$ such that $\sqrt{9-8\sin 50^{\circ}}=a+b\sin c^{\circ}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359594/find-this-a-b-c-such-that-sqrt9-8-sin-50-circ-ab-sin-c-circ?rq=1)

I had post in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193974/how-solve-this-transcendental-equation-with-a-1-b-4-c-10-is-unique-solution):if we can prove $c=10$ is unique solution,Then I can solve it

Comment: see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+solutions+1%2B4sin+10%3Da%2Bb*sin+c)

Comment: Are you sure with the $\pm$ of the solutions? I think the plus signs are OK, but maybe not the minus signs.

Comment: @mickep,can you find other  integer solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer.** This is a *partial answer*, namely for the case that $\,b > 0$ .
All quantities $\,a,b,c\,$ in the problem are integers,
the range of the sine is restricted to $\,0 < \sin < 1$
and the reference value is $\;1+4\sin(10^\circ) \approx 1.7\;$ .
This makes that all of the available choices of the variables *maybe aren't that
numerous* . It's easy to see that $\,a\,$ cannot be anything else than $a = 1$
for $b > 0$ , if we deliberately ignore the case $\;b < 0\;$ for the moment being. The minimal value of the sine
is $\,\sin(1^\circ)$ , so the possible values of $b > 0$ are bounded by $\;4\sin(10^\circ)/\sin(1^\circ) < 40$ . The
only thing left is to loop through all possible values of $\;c^\circ\;$
and see what happens. The Pascal program below is our  implementation of the ideas.

```
program math110;

procedure medium_force;
const
  eps : double = 1.E-6;
var
  b,c,max,tel : integer;
  value,ref,min : double;
begin
  ref := 1+4*sin(10*Pi/180);
  Writeln('1+4.sin(10) = ',ref);
  min := sin(1*Pi/180);
  max := Trunc(4*sin(10*Pi/180)/min)+1;
  Writeln('0 < b < ',max);
  Writeln;
  tel := 0;
  for b := 1 to max do
  begin
    for c := 1 to 89 do
    begin
      tel := tel + 1;
      value := 1+b*sin(c*Pi/180);
      if (abs(value - ref) < eps) and not (value = ref)
        then Writeln('value <> reference'); { Safety check }
      if value = ref then Writeln('value = reference'); 
      if value = ref then Writeln('for a = ',1,' b = ',b,' c = ',c);
      if value > ref then Break; { Not a chance anymore }
    end;
  end;
  Writeln;
  Writeln('# trials = ',tel);
end;

begin
  medium_force;
end.
```

Output:

```
1+4.sin(10) =  1.69459271066772E+0000
0 < b < 40

value = reference
for a = 1 b = 4 c = 10

# trials = 196
```

Note that a "safety check" has been built in against machine rounding errors.
Herewith it is proved that $\;a=1,b= 4,c=10\;$ is indeed a unique solution,
*provided that* $\,b > 0$ . Now heading for the case $\,b < 0$ , eventually.